# UIDatePicker customize available time intervals

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

Is it possible to set in `UIDatePicker`, date/time frames selectively? for example: show only Mondays from 8am to 4pm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this with standard `UIDatePicker`. Instead you should build your own custom date picker based on `UIPickerView`.